# prime ideals of $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X-Y^2,X+Y)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm trying to understand an example in my lecture notes, it states that $Spec(\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X-Y^2,X+Y))$ has only two points. Can anyone develop more please ? and how would these points be like ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you know the geometric picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximal ideals containing $(X-Y^2,X+Y)$ are $(X,Y)$ and $(X-1,Y+1)$.
To see this, the ideal $(X-Y^2,X+Y)$ has $Y^2+Y$ has an element, and so
either $Y$ or $Y+1$. If it contains $Y$ it contains $X$, and if it contains
$Y+1$, it contains $X-1$.